# Проблема с доступом к tfs из VS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, tfs

Пытаюсь через VS подключиться к TFS (доступ по VPN, без MS-аккаунта, через вводимые вручную логин/пароль), выдаёт ошибку TF30063 - нет прав доступа. Пользуюсь Visual Studio 2017. Через встроенный в VS браузер ситуация аналогичная. Через IE/Edge/Chrome доступ есть. 
Вышел из MS-аккаунта в VS - не помогло.
Пробовал перезагружать VS/компьютер - не помогло.
Пробовал, согласно одному из советов, чистить кеш/куки/историю в IE/Edge - не помогло.
На очереди, если других решений не найдётся, переустановка VS.

Comment: Переустановка VS не помогла.

Comment: Полная очистка кеша IE и VS - не помогла.

Comment: Установил VS 2013 - аналогичная ситуация, но добавилась ошибка TF31003.

Comment: Установил VS 2010 - ошибка TF31003, т.е. ничего не изменилось, по сути.

Comment: Удалил все VS. Удалил SSMS. Очистил %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\. Сменил язык Windows. Установил VS 17. Каким-то чудом к tfs подключиться получилось.